# float image within text

Tags: html, css, image

I need to float an image (its actually a flash banner in the end result) within text, but each are arriving from a different CMS. So my DOM result is:

```
<img src="" alt=""/>
<p>All text here</p>
```

Is there a way using client-side methods to make the image float within the text? (So it will be a little to the bottom but still have the text wrapping it)
as if the markup was like this:

```
<p>Star of text</p>
<img src="" alt=""/>
<p>End of text</p>
```

I used a fiddle to try and get some example going: http://jsfiddle.net/F3ZyF/5/

Comment: Have you tried actually making the markup what you've suggested in your second code snippet?

Comment: In this case, you need some JavaScript to place the `img` (or banner) element some place further down the DOM.

Comment: Solved! Thank you Marc. I used insertAfter() in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`<p>Start of Text<img src="" alt="" style="align:bottom;">End of Text</p>`
Notice I added `style="align:bottom;` and put the `img` tag inside the `p` tag.

Comment: The problem the OP is facing is that the image/banner appears first in the mark-up (outside of his control) and he wants to place it some place else.  Your CSS will work of course but you still need to manipulate the DOM using JavaScript/jQuery to place the image/banner in the new position.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of a jQuery based solution:

```
banner_wrap = $( ".article-box-banner-wrap" ).detach();
$(".article-text p").first().after(banner_wrap);
```

Use the `.detach()` function to remove the banner element from the DOM and then use `.after()` (or similar) to reinsert the banner after the first `p`.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Q2ADA/